# Which memory structures are shared between a parent and child process?

Tags: process, fork, pipe, parent-child, shared-memory

I feel like there aren't any memory structures that are shared between the two processes because the only way for them to communicate is through pipes.

Comment: Shared memory is shared, open file descriptors are shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's not true.

Pipes are generally used for sharing data between two or more processes, in a single user system environment.

Whereas, shared memory is widely used and is most popular in industry for sharing data among different processes in multi-user system environment.

[Go for more here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory)